# ref is null Typescript + NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ref, use-ref

I need to call methods from a custom child component inside the parent component.

But unfortunately the ref to the child component (called CanvasUI) is always null. I don't understand why as it seems to me that I have implemented everything correctly.

This is my parent component

```js
...

export default function Home() {
  ...
  const canvas = useRef<CanvasRef>(null);

  ...
  function clearCanvas() {
    // canvas.current.resetCanvas();
    console.log(canvas.current);
  }
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center items-center min-h-screen min-w-screen bg-main">
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        ...
        <div className="flex justify-center">
          ...
          <CanvasUI disabled={disableCanvas} word={activeWord} ref={canvas} />
          ...
        </div>
        ...
        <button onClick={() => clearCanvas()}>clear canvas</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is the CanvasUI component

```js
...

export default function CanvasUI({
  disabled,
  word,
  ref,
}: {
  disabled: boolean;
  word: string;
  ref: Ref<CanvasRef>;
}) {
  ...
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ getCanvas, loadCanvas, resetCanvas }));

  ...

  function resetCanvas(): void {
    ...
  }

  ...

  function getCanvas(): String {
    ...
  }

  function loadCanvas(data: String, immediate: Boolean): void {
    ...
  }

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

CanvasRef Interface

```js
export default interface CanvasRef {
  getCanvas: () => String;
  loadCanvas: (data: String, immediate: Boolean) => void;
  resetCanvas: () => void;
}
```

I left out unimportant code to make it more readable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `ref` as a prop in a component because it is reserved [<sup>1</sup>](https://legacy.reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html) [<sup>2</sup>](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#common-props) [<sup>3</sup>](https://react.dev/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe#picking-a-key) (just like `key`). React will omit the `ref` prop from `props` when invoking your function component.

Instead, you should position `ref` as the second parameter to your `CanvasUI` component, and then create it using [`forwardRef`](https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef). This is explained in the documentation for [`useImperativeHandle`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useImperativeHandle):

> ### useImperativeHandle
>
> ```js
> useImperativeHandle(ref, createHandle, [deps])
> ```
>
> `useImperativeHandle` customizes the instance value that is exposed to parent components when using `ref`. As always, imperative code using refs should be avoided in most cases. `useImperativeHandle` should be used with [`forwardRef`](https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef):
>
> ```js
> function FancyInput(props, ref) {
>   const inputRef = useRef();
>   useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
>     focus: () => {
>       inputRef.current.focus();
>     }
>   }));
>   return <input ref={inputRef} ... />;
> }
> FancyInput = forwardRef(FancyInput);
> ```
>
> In this example, a parent component that renders `<FancyInput ref={inputRef} />` would be able to call `inputRef.current.focus()`.