# Getting Property 'height' does not exist on type 'string' TypeScript Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-ref

I'm using `useRef` to reference a div element and storing `getBoundingClientRect()`. Upon using it, I get a TypeScript error of `Property 'height' does not exist on type 'string'`. How do I address this error?

```
const divRef = useRef(null);
const [divSize, setDivSize] = useState("0");

setDivSize(divRef.current.getBoundingClientRect());

console.log(divSize.height); // getting TS error: Property 'height' does not exist on type 'string'.

return (
  <Content ref={divRef}>
     {content}
  </Content>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic type with `useRef` to something that has `getBoundingClientRect` as a valid method, such as `HTMLElement` or `HTMLDivElement`:

```
const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
```

That should properly allow to access `height` of result of `getBoundingClientRect()`.

This is purely a solution for typing. The answer by jsejcksn help explain how to handle falsy/undefined ref in an effective way.

Comment: Similar with the other answer, I'm now getting this error `Argument of type 'DOMRect' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<number>'.`

Comment: @EricNguyen what value do you actually want to save? The height as a number? The height as a string? The entire DOM rec object? It’s not clear what you want to save in state and as what type.

Answer (score 0):

Unconditionally calling a `setState` function at the top level of any component is always an error, because it initiates the reconciliation algorithm (infinitely). Here is a note from the React documentation (which needs to be updated for functional components):

> You **may call `setState()` immediately** in `componentDidUpdate()` but note that **it must be wrapped in a condition** like in the example above, or you’ll cause an infinite loop.
>
> ↳ https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

To fix this, wrap the `setState` call in [the effect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

```js
const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
const [divSize, setDivSize] = useState(new DOMRect());

useEffect(() => {
  if (!divRef.current) return;
  const rect = divRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
  setDivSize(rect);
  console.log(rect.height);
});

return (
  <Content ref={divRef}>
     {content}
  </Content>
)
```

[Also, you can't use the `ref` prop on a functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70365476/438273).

Comment: I tried this but now getting this error: `Argument of type 'DOMRect' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<number>'`

Comment: @EricNguyen sure it would be `setDivSize(divRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height);`. I didn't focus on that aspect as the error was surrounding the typing of the ref.

Comment: Ah, I was trying to avoid setting a specific value to a variable, but wanted to save the entire `DOMRect` to a variable.

Comment: @EricNguyen I’m not at a computer to test it right now, but you might try using the following as the initial argument to `useState` instead of `0`: `new DOMRect(0, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: @EricNguyen I updated my answer with the new initial state value.